# Join two tables with one table has multiple rows matching

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

Trying to figure out if it is possible to create a query where you join tables, table one is smaller than table two, table two has multiple references matching table one entries, the query would output a joining where table one length is preserved but you just add more columns. Not sure if that makes sense so here is a example of what I am after

```
Table One                                  Table two
+-----------------------------+           +-----------------------------+
| id | english  |  definition |           | id | word_id  |  sentence   |
+-----------------------------+           +-----------------------------+
|1   |    A1    |    blah     |           |1   |    1    |   blahblah1  |
|2   |    B4    |    blah2    |           |2   |    1    |   blahblah2  |
+-----------------------------+           |3   |    1    |   blahblah3  |
                                          |4   |    2    |   blahblah4  |
                                          |5   |    2    |   blahblah5  |
                                          +-----------------------------+
```

********* Query should return something like *****************

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | english  |  definition | sentence | sentence2 | sentence3 | 
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   |    A1    |    blah     | blahblah1|  blahblah2| blahblah3 |
|2   |    B4    |    blah2    | blahblah4|  blahblah5|           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My Current query looks like this and results in:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.word_id";
```

Resulting in:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| id | english  |  definition | sentence |
+----------------------------------------+
|1   |    A1    |    blah     | blahblah1|
|1   |    A1    |    blah     | blahblah2|
|1   |    A1    |    blah     | blahblah3| 
|2   |    B4    |    blah2    | blahblah4|
|2   |    B4    |    blah2    | blahblah5|
+----------------------------------------+
```

I am working with PHP and MySql.

UPDATE!!

Staying with my original query and manipulating the results with PHP getting good performance too. Let me know if you need me to post my code.

Comment: It seems to me that what you are trying to achieve is some sort of a PIVOT table. See this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx as an example. But I do not think this will work given how your data is organized.

Comment: I'd recommend staying with your original query and formatting the result in your PHP code. To get your desired results in MySQL requires knowing (a) the maximum number of sentences per `Table1.ID` and (2) how to order the sentences. Even when you have this information it's an incredibly complicated query.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.english,T1.definition,
GROUP_CONCAT(T2.sentence ORDER BY T2.ID SEPARATOR '|') 
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.word_id
Group by word_id
```

**[*Sample fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da5f2/3)**

Comment: When you use `GROUP_CONCAT` with a `LEFT JOIN`, you need to use a `GROUP BY` statement as well in order to get rows that have no need for the `GROUP_CONCAT` if that makes sense. Basically without the `GROUP BY` statement it turned my LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN.

Comment: I see this question has been answered a long time ago but I've got a question of my own regarding this subject. When I use this GROUP_CONCAT function, how would I do "AND word_id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)"?

Comment: Do set filtered data into a resultset. Apply group_concat to that result set.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. Simply because there's unknown number of columns (say, if you add one more sentence to the top word you could be adding one more column to the result set) and each column is not well defined ( Why blahblah4  should be in column sentence instead of sentence2 ?)

IMO, SQL is used to tell what you want to get, but in this case, SQL is unable to tell exactly what you want.

Even if  this can be done ( I would love to learn ), I believe the complexity offsets any benefit and handling this in PHP is a better option.